# Converting a date into milliseconds

Tags: java

I have a database that holds times at which i need to run certain processes
I do a query which gives me the difference between the current time and the time at which i'm supposed to run the process
For example, I might get this number 23:49:44.835 which means i need to run the process in about 23 hours. 
I want to get this process in milliseconds, so I have done this

```
Date Date = (java.util.Date) (InMsgTstable[index][0]);
long Value3 = Date.getTime();
```

The date value i get is correct, though it drops the milliseconds value that is stored in my database.
I want to get this number of hours/minutes etc.. in milliseconds so i can put that number as a millisecond delay in a scheduler. However, this is giving me the wrong value in milliseconds.
Any tips?

Comment: To clarify, the numbers you get are off by upto +- 999 millis, right? You are not saying that your numbers are off by a *factor* of 1000...

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. You get the correct hours, minutes, seconds and millis in your `Date` object?

Comment: well as it stands now, if i have the following hours i get the following milliseconds 22:38:56
99536699  if i convert i see that's about 5 hours off. not quite sure what the cause of this is. also i'm not sure if getTime gets time since 1970 because i don't want that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in control of the database table, I would change the column type to an integer type and simply store the timestamp in milliseconds as an integer value.

That will allow you to treat the value as the timestamp that `Date` and `Calendar` use natively without having to handle the conversions that databases perform on date and time columns.

**Edit**

From your comment above I see that the value you get looks like the number of milliseconds since the start of the current day (which is by definition localtime, so beware of timezone values in the database.)

The date that you create using this timestamp is situated in Jan 1 1970, which is not what you want.

What you could do is to create a calendar object which defaults to "now", back-up to the start of day and get that timestamp to add to the value you got from the database, something like (untested):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

long stamp = cal.getTime().getTime() + msgTableValue;

Date dat = new Date(stamp);
```

which should give you a `Date` object representing `msgTableValue` milliseconds into the current day.

Comment: the database is actually a kdb+ database and the dates are q objects which i can convert to a java date

Comment: @MatthewPiatetsky, what is actually stored in the q object? An integer long value or a date/time value? Storing the timestamp in the form of a long integer saves you on interpretation to/from the database store.

Comment: not quite sure but i'm not in control of this database I'm just writing a program for it. the q objects are used for real time high volume ticker data and stuff but when i bring in the times with a method i can get it as a date object. i think q has its own class for timestamps or something

Comment: this looks pretty close. just a bit confused though what exactly is msgTableValue? Is it the date object i was getting? Because i was getting a date object from the database and then using getTime

Comment: @MatthewPiatetsky, yes that was the idea - msgTablevalue would be your millies value, it looks like what you get from the database only has the millies part of a date, so you need to add it to the start of the current day in millies to get a valid timestamp.

Comment: so this was actually not quite working, but i solved it a different way, by just getting the hours minutes and seconds. The only problem is the date seems to be truncating the milliseconds and i'm not quite sure how to get them. I think the object is actually java.sql.Time and I don't think that has milliseconds in it so i'm probably losing that

Comment: @MatthewPiatetskym you could try to get a long integer value from the field and see if that includes the milliseconds. (let the databse abstraction  layer take care of conversion)

Comment: I don' think i can get the long value. This is how i get it.  String query = "`time$(select InMsgTS from InMsg) - `time$.z.Z";
  TimeScheduletable = makeQueries(query);
  Date date = (java.util.Date) TimeScheduletable[index][0]; // Extract the time as a date object
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  Long delay = (long) (((((date.getHours() * 60) + date.getMinutes())* 60 ) + date.getSeconds()) * 1000);

Comment: This is the makeQueries method    String q = query;
  Object o = qConn.k(q);
  c.Flip d = c.td(o); 
  int cols = c.n(d.x);
  int rows = c.n(d.y[0]);

  Object[][] oo = new Object[rows][cols];
  for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
   for (int cc = 0; cc < cols; cc++) {
    oo[r][cc] = c.at(d.y[cc], r);
   }
  }
  return oo;

Comment: the stuff is stored in weird tables/dictionaries so if i try to cast to something like string or long it won't work. I'm actually casting it to date and i think its coming out as java.sql.Time

Comment: @MatthewPiatetsky, it actually returns a Date object, otehrwise you would get a ClassCastException. I don't know the database youre using, using `date.getTime()` is probably the closest to getting the milliseconds as long integer as you can get.